# Usando array para colocar várias classes em uma DIV

Tags: php

Quero colocar várias classes em uma `div`, utilizando `Array`, como poderia faze-lo? Tentei utilizando o código abaixo, mas não deu certo.

```
<?php 
    $minhas_classes = array(
        'main-content' => 'main-content', 
        'post-count' => 'post-count', 
        'loop-style' => 'loop-style',
        'has-image' => 'has-image',
    );
?>

<div class="<?php echo $minhas_classes; ?>">
</div>
```

Comment: A última `,`(virgula) do seu `array` não é necessária, fora isso, não entendi completamente o que você precisa. Poderia dar algum exemplo?

Comment: Mas para imprimir um conteúdo do `array` seria assim: `echo $minhas_classes["post-count"];`, dessa forma seria impresso o segundo conteúdo.

Comment: Não da para imprimir todas de uma vez só? Sem ter que repetir isso: $minhas_classes["post-count"], $minhas_classes["main-content"]

Comment: Qual a ideia de se ter um array associativo sendo que a chave é igual ao valor?

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss  Entendi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu particularmente não entendi porque você definiu um *array* associativo, sendo que as chaves são iguais aos valores. Ao meu ver, um *array* sequencial já bastaria e ficaria até mais simples.

```
$classes = ['main-content', 'post-count', 'loop-style', 'has-image'];
```

Para exibir todas de uma vez, basta converter seu *array* para *string* com a função **[`join`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.join.php)**

```
$classes = join(' ', $classes);
```

Assim, basta fazer:

```
echo "<div class=\"{$classes}\">";
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/1PeKGE) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/TautAnnualMoa)</sup>

O resultado será, como esperado:

```
<div class="main-content post-count loop-style has-image">
```

Comment: Era isso, é exatamente isso que eu procurava. Problema resolvido. Obrigado.